# Access VBA for loop (date)

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access, for-loop

I have been tried to loop the data from 2011/12/04 to 2011/12/10 in the access VBA. But an error of '3075' occur when I try to run the code. I can't figure out where is the problem of my code. Hope you could help me with this!

```
Private Sub createQry()

'Create Query in Access
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim newSQL As String




For d = DateSerial(2011, 12, 4) To DateSerial(2011, 12, 10)


newSQL = " SELECT TAXIDATA.HkDt, TAXIDATA.DevID, TAXIDATA.HkTm, TAXIDATA.Lat, TAXIDATA.Lon, TAXIDATA.FlagDown" 'sql code
newSQL = newSQL & "FROM TAXIDATA"
newSQL = newSQL & "WHERE(((TAXIDATA.HkDt) = #" & d & "#))"
newSQL = newSQL & " ORDER BY TAXIDATA.HkDt, TAXIDATA.DevID, TAXIDATA.HkTm; "


Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(d, newSQL)                  'd = name of the query

'Export the Access query into excel

Dim XL As Excel.Application
Dim wbTarget As Workbook

Dim queryD As QueryDef
Dim RecordA As Recordset

Set queryD = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(d)
Set RecordA = queryD.OpenRecordset()

Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.application")

Set wbTarget = XL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Data\123.xlsx")    ' location of the workbook

wbTarget.Worksheets(d).Cells.ClearContents                         ' name of the worksheets in the workbook

wbTarget.Worksheets(d).Cells(1.1).CopyFromRecordset RecordA

wbTarget.Save

wbTarget.Close
Set wbTarget = Nothing
Set XL = Nothing
Set queryD = Nothing



   Debug.Print Days  'Prints the "Days" value in the immediate window.
Next d


End Sub
```

Comment: Where does the error 3075 occur?  If it is when you are executing the query, try formatting `d` to be a date format.

Comment: `FROM` and `WHERE` need  a space in front like the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

It's really unlikely this has anything to do with the `for` loop.
The likely culprit is your query:

Change the newSQL assignment to this:

```
newSQL = " SELECT TAXIDATA.HkDt, TAXIDATA.DevID, TAXIDATA.HkTm, TAXIDATA.Lat, TAXIDATA.Lon, TAXIDATA.FlagDown" 'sql code
newSQL = newSQL & " FROM TAXIDATA"
newSQL = newSQL & " WHERE TAXIDATA.HkDt = #" & Format(d, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "#"
newSQL = newSQL & " ORDER BY TAXIDATA.HkDt, TAXIDATA.DevID, TAXIDATA.HkTm; "
```

This fixes the following bugs:

1. Missing space (space added on line 3 and 4)
2. Unspecified date format, format function added on line 3 (valid formats are `yyyy/MM/dd` or `MM/dd/yyyy`, not specifying will cause errors depending on locale settings

Please try to debug your SQL first next time, I might miss an errror if you have lots of them.

Comment: 1) Parenthesis were just fine (except the spacing after the WHERE clause) - this is the format the query editor uses.
2) Unformatted date does not throw an error. It simply doesn’t return the desired result.

Comment: @KostasK. Thank you, missed one closing parenthesis. Just excessive use of them, though. For point 2, it doesn't cause the error (point 1 does), but still is a bug in my opinion (the program will not behave as expected).

Comment: @KostasK.: Erik is right. You must apply a format to the date value or it will be casted to whatever the Windows settings define.

Comment: @Gustav Indeed, never argued that, I only said that it doesn't throw a runtime error. As it turns out, it's a matter of the error definition.

Comment: @KostasK. Ah, I see. No, it wouldn't raise an error.

Comment: @KostasK. The not throwing an error part is still relative, by the way. If you've got your locale settings to `dd.MM.yyyy`, that actually throws a `Syntax error in query expression`. And that's a locale setting that's actually used by some countries (Belgium, for example).